# Privilege Violation

Tags: files-and-directories

I am working with a file that is about 400Mb. The intent is to read in the information, transform the data and output to a new file. Before writing to a new file, the directory is checked for an existing version. If an existing version is present, it should be deleted.

When I evaluate the code, I receive a privilege violation. I'm working on my personal laptop and am the administrator. The code is listed below.

```
(* Input *)
SetDirectory[ NotebookDirectory[] ];
nameCheck = "medium.dat";
file      = FileNameJoin[{ NotebookDirectory[],nameCheck }];
condition = MemberQ[ FileNames[], nameCheck ];

If[ condition, DeleteFile[ file ] ]

(* Output *)
DeleteFile::privv: Privilege violation during DeleteFile[C:\Users\Miles\workspace\SEG\medium.dat]. >>
```

How do I modify the privileges?

Comment: This error usually means that another process is holding the file open. [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) should be able to identify which process it is.

Comment: or the file is read-only?

Comment: you will get that error if you opened and forgot to close it in mathematica...

Comment: What exact is the message you get? Did you try this already in a new kernel session ?